# Angular 2 Warning

Tags: angular2-directives

Can anyone help me on how to get rid of these warnings?

> npm WARN angular2-jsonapi@3.5.1 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.4.9 but none was installed.
>
> npm WARN angular2-jsonapi@3.5.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.9 but none was installed.

Comment: Try to update the packages to latest version by using npm-check-updates.

Answer (score 0):

It is known issue. You can find it here https://github.com/ghidoz/angular2-jsonapi/issues/80

There is nothing wrong with your package.json
However, some users reported that warnings disappeared after performing npm install for the second time.